# XOR two hex strings

Tags: php, xor

I want to XOR two strings (hex-encoded) in php.
I have tried using operator ^, but I get only 0.
How can I do that? Why is it wrong?

Comment: What if the strings are not valid hexadecimal strings? What if they are of a different length?

Comment: If it is only 32-bit, you can probably sscanf it to an integer and do XOR. If it is more you may need to write your own function.

Comment: the key thing to note is that ^ will convert its operands to a number, it will not operate on arbitrary length strings. So, you'll need loop through your string, converting one octet at a time.

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php 
    $s1 = 'ABCDEF1234567890';
    $s2 = '0987654321ABCDEF';
    $x = bin2hex(pack('H*',$s1) ^ pack('H*',$s2));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks lawl0r - I should have come back and commented myself as I found this to be the case. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

```
$x = dechex(hexdec($s1) ^ hexdec($s2));
```

http://codepad.org/fgRfAPAI

The problem, that you initially had is, that a hex-string is in fact a string. When you use binary operators on strings, it uses the character-codes as byte value.

Comment: that won't work for arbitrary length strings - but he could adapt your technique to do it octet by octet

Comment: Yeah, if over a 32-bit integer range than epic fail.

Comment: @KingCrunch that's a way to enhance your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode them with [hex2bin()](http://php.net/hex2bin) before you apply the [XOR `^` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

**Update:** I always forget that this function requires PHP/5.4 or greater, which can be an issue. In such case, you need to use the not very intuitive [pack()](http://php.net/pack) function:

```
$binary = pack('H*', $hexadecimal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @KingCrunch's answer here and the comments I wrote this simple loop to compare octets and build up the answer. Interestingly, this has the same result as @lawlor's answer.

```
$key1 = 'ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890';
$key2 = '0987654321ABCDEF0987654321ABCDEF';

$key1_octets = str_split($key1, 2);
$key2_octets = str_split($key2, 2);
$xor = '';
foreach ($key1_octets as $id => $key1_octet) {
  $xor .= dechex(hexdec($key1_octets[$id]) ^ hexdec($key2_octets[$id]));
}
print $xor;

print bin2hex(pack('H*',$key1) ^ pack('H*',$key2));
```

I'm not actually sure if either one is a valid result, but I put this forth for feedback and in case it helps someone else who is looking at @KingCrunch's answer without knowing how to deal with the octets.